# how to get width of ul on the base of class jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

How can get width of `<ul>` on the class name as class name will be unique for each `<ul>`.

I don't want to select by `id`, but rather by `class` so it can be reused,

My `<ul>` html is:

```
<ul id="cat-sec-bar" class="RestaurantssubTypeDivClass" style="display: block;">
    //some code here
</ul>
```

I am trying with this:

```
 var divWidth = $(".RestaurantssubTypeDivClass").width();
 //Getting 0
```

What is wrong here?
any other way to do it?

Comment: Please clarify `I dont want to check width on the base id of ul.`

Comment: It mean that I dont want to do it like: $("#cat-sec-bar").width();

Comment: Then don't use it. However `var divWidth = $(".RestaurantssubTypeDivClass").width();` works see http://jsfiddle.net/h82cj/

Comment: @Satpal indeed, meaning the `#some code here` is probably not filled with `<li>`'s at all

Comment: yes,there is <li> in it.

Comment: @Test Then replace the `some code here` with an actual example, secondly, are the lists populated dynamically?

Comment: @MackieeE yes,It is working in jsfiddle. but not working in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var divWidth = $(".RestaurantssubTypeDivClass").css('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

actually there will be many ul shortlisted  in basis of class so you ll have to take widths in array , then you need to precess array :

**Class can be Duplicate.  Id's are Unique.**

```
 var divWidth = [];

$(".RestaurantssubTypeDivClass").each( function(){

 divWidth.push(  $(this).width());

})
```

Comment: @Test - edited code . basically divWidth array definition was wrong.

Comment: hey I try this $("#"+divIdUl).css("border","4px solid red");
    var divWidth = $("#"+divIdUl).width();
    
    console.log(divIdUl+'ppp==>>>>'+divWidth);
but getting -4 on console .